# LINQ with AND or OR for 2 or more enumerable lists

Tags: c#, linq

So I have 2 different lists, say services and groups. Groups contain services. I'm trying to figure out a linq join between them. I've got an interface that allows the user to select one or many services and I need a query to that will select all groups that either have all selected services in them, or all groups that have at least one of the selected services in them. The and/or segment is selected via radios.

```
var servFilter = from cs in lstServices.CheckedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                         join ts in TotalServices on cs.Tag equals ts.IDserv
                         join fg in groupSet on ts.IDpack equals fg.IDPack
                         select fg;
```

This is what I have so far, and seems to be handling the 'or' aspect of it, I just can't wrap my head around how I would 'and' this.

For clarity:
Say I have Group1 & 2, and Service1,2, & 3. Group1 has service 1 & 3. Group2 has service 1 & 2. If you selected service 1 and 2, the way the code is now you would get both groups (the Or, both groups contain Service 1 not necessarily service 2). I'm looking for a query that would only give me Group 2 since it is the only group that contains both Service 1 AND Service 2

Comment: where is "groups" in your code?

Comment: @DLeh packFilter, just edited for clarity to groupSet

Comment: You need two queries.  All and at least one can't be combined.

Comment: @jdweng Yeah I get that, I just can't wrap my head around how to put the 'and' query together. Joining just gives me the or, so how would I join to get 'and'?

Comment: do you mean `Concat()` or `Union()` to bring them into a single list?

Comment: @DLeh No, I'm looking to get a list of only groups that contain all of the selected services. The code I have above gives me a list of groups that contain any of the selected services.

Comment: Permform the or'd on the join.  You can use contains to do or.

Comment: What is the type of `IDPack` and `IDServ` (i.e. `int`, `string` etc.)?

Comment: @jdweng the code above does 'or' natively.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev IDPack is string, IDServ is int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var query = (from g in groupSet
              join s in TotalServices on g.IDpack equals s.IDpack
              group new {s, g} by g into grp
              select new
              {
                 Group = grp.Key,
                 Services = grp
              }).Where(x => !lstServices.CheckedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x1 => x1.Tag).Except(x.Services.Select(x2 => x2.Services.IDserv)).Any()).Select(a => a.Group).ToList();
```

Actually you don't need the `select new`, here a better looking code :

```
var query = (from g in groupSet
             join s in TotalServices on g.IDpack equals s.IDpack
             group new { s, g } by g into grp
             where !lstServices.CheckedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x1 => x1.Tag).Except(grp.Select(x2 => x2.s.IDserv)).Any()
             select grp.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: I'll look into this, but to clarify, say I have Group1 & 2, and Service1,2, & 3. Group1 has service 1 & 3. Group2 has service 1 & 2. If you selected service 1 and 2, the way the code is now you would get both groups (the Or, both groups contain Service 1). I'm looking for a query that would only give me Group 2 since it is the only group that contains both Service 1 AND Service 2.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Just doesn't return any results. The Groups and Services are Model Objects, and the contains is looking for a ListViewItem, of which I create them all dynamically, so to use contains I have to compare against a newly created LVI using the same conventions as the others (basically just the name of the group with the ID in the control tag). It doesn't seem to be able to find anything. servFilter.ToArray() just returns 0 elements no matter how many services I select, or which groups they're apart of.

Comment: I was able to get this to return some results in a console app finally, but it still gives me both groups, instead of just one (the OR condition).

Comment: Happy to help, I made some improvements though. You should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do both:

```
var selectedServiceIds = lstServices.CheckedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(cs => cs.Tag);

var anySelected = groupSet.Where(fg => TotalServices.Any(
    ts => ts.IDpack == fg.IDPack && selectedServiceIds.Contains(ts.IDserv)));

var allSelected = groupSet.Where(fg => selectedServiceIds.All(
    id => TotalServices.Any(ts => ts.IDpack == fg.IDPack && ts.IDserv == id)));
```

Comment: This kind of works. After some testing here's what I saw:  
If I have:  
G1 - S1, S3  
G2 - S1, S2  
G3 - S1, S2, S3  
  
SelectedService = 1, 2  
Gives: G2  
Expected: G2, G3  
  
SelectedService = 1, 3  
Gives: G1  
Expected: G1, G3  
  
SelectedService = 1, 2, 3  
Gives: G1, G2, G3  
Expected: G3

Comment: SelectedService = 2, 3
Gives: null
Expected: G3

Comment: @ZexksMarquise Yeah, I messed up a little the conditions. See the update, it's simple and self explanatory - every selected item must have a corresponding service for a group in order to include that group.